# Use Pi 3 With Waveshare 3.5" and MFRC522

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3

This message showed up when I was using MFRC522 along with Waveshare LCD 3.5"(A) on Raspberry Pi 3:

```
python Read.py 
can't open device: No such file or directory Aborted
```

I think it's because SPI is used with the LCD, correct me if I'm wrong. Is it possible to make MFRC522 and Waveshare LCD 3.5"(A) work together?

Comment: Could you please add more detail (or code) into what you are doing with the MFR?

Comment: @sir_ian first I install LCD driver by following instrution here [wavesharedriver](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)), after that the LCD are Working. after that I'm following instruction here For installing MFRC522 [MFRC522](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=147291)

Comment: It's because of the screen.

Comment: Thanks All, I've found the solution by installing Pigpiod then using MFRC522 on SPI1 and the LCD still work on SPI0.

Answer (score 1):

I've Found Solution by installing [Pigpio Library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) and use RC522 on SPI1 and LCD on SPI0